# How to store images in ArangoDB?

Tags: java, arangodb, arangojs

I want to store images in ArangoDb as image file. I want to know if there is any API or Java API for the same. Thanking You in advance.

Comment: there is no binary support in ArangoDB yet, you could store it as Base64 encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Storing binary data inside ArangoDB has been a long standing feature request](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/107).
Currently its not possible out of the box.

One can however do this by creating a foxx service that handles the data.
The recommended way is to create a file and reference that file name inside the database.

A detailed description and an [example foxx app can be found in the cookbook](https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/FoxxBinaryFileUploads.html)

Comment: I've updated the article, have a look at http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2014/10/15/handling-binary-data-in-foxx/

Comment: Handling binary data in ArangoDB v3.x: http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2016/06/22/handling-binary-data-in-foxx-3-0/